# How to change the color scheme in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to change the color palette to two arbitrary HEX colors. How can I do it in the chart below?

```
hec <- as.data.frame(xtabs(Freq ~ Hair + Eye, HairEyeColor))

hec %>% 
  ggvis(~Hair, ~Eye, fill = ~Freq) %>% 
  layer_rects(width = band(), height = band()) %>%
  scale_nominal("x", padding = 0, points = FALSE) %>%
  scale_nominal("y", padding = 0, points = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the start and end colors of the fill color palette?  That'd be something like `scale_numeric("fill", range = c("red", "green"))`.

Comment: @aosmith Yes thanks, I was keeping trying `scale_nominal("fill", range = c("red", "green"))` but it wasn't working of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `range` in `scale_numeric` to change the start and end of a continuous fill gradient.

For example, if you wanted a range of red to green you would use

```
scale_numeric("fill", range = c("red", "green"))
```